# Oracle SQL, not exist and count

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently stuck with my assignment. I am not trying to be lazy but I can't seems to find a solution and my teacher guided me by saying to use not exist or count.

I need to find patients name who have been treated by all the doctors. Currently I am just using plain intersect SQL command for each doctor name (In the question, there are only 3 doctors) but of course its not realistic when there are 100's of doctors name.

The scheme is as below.

Patient (PatientID, FamilyName, GivenName)

Account (ProviderNo, PatientID)

Doctor (ProviderNo, Name)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for "relational division"

Comment: Will do right away! Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I won't provide you the exact `Query`.

But here is the **psuedo code**:

```
group PatientId in Account where its distinct ProviderNo count should be 
equal to no. of Doctors
```